# How to help Android find weak WiFi signal?

Tags: wi-fi

There are a couple of places at home that are pretty far away from my router and barely have wifi connection.

That means if I go there with my phone connected to the network, I have a connection but if I loose the connection, the network doesn't show up in the wifi results. Then I have to go back to a spot closer to the router and "catch" the connection again and I can go back to surf from the original spot.

Is there a way to tell Android not to ignore weak connections in the search window?